# Split columns into rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have my input in a Pandas dataframe in the following format.

[image: Input data]

I would like to convert it into the below format

[image]

What I have managed to do so far:

I managed to extract the col values `A` and `B` from the column names have have cross joined it with the name column to obtain the following dataframe. I am not sure if my approach is correct.

[image]

I am not sure how I should go about it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: kindly share data, not pics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the earlier comment about posting data/code, but in this case it's simple enough to type in an example:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame( { 'Name' : ['AA','BB','CC'],
                     'col1_A' : [5,2,5],
                     'col2_A' : [10,3,6],
                     'col1_B' : [15,4,7],
                     'col2_B' : [20,6,21],
                   })

print(df)

  Name  col1_A  col2_A  col1_B  col2_B
0   AA       5      10      15      20
1   BB       2       3       4       6
2   CC       5       6       7      21
```

You can create a `pd.MultiIndex` to replace the column names to match the structure of the table:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],['val_1','val_2']], names=('col', None))

print(df)
col      A           B      
     val_1 val_2 val_1 val_2
Name                        
AA       5    10    15    20
BB       2     3     4     6
CC       5     6     7    21
```

Then `stack()` the `'col'` column index, and reset both indices to be columns:

```
df = df.stack('col').reset_index()
print(df)

  Name col  val_1  val_2
0   AA   A      5     10
1   AA   B     15     20
2   BB   A      2      3
3   BB   B      4      6
4   CC   A      5      6
5   CC   B      7     21
```

Comment: I just thought there must be some way we can using `df.stack().reset_index()` directly, but I doesn't search deep with this thought, you did it, good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Dummy dataframe
d = {'Name': ['AA', 'BB'], 'col1_A': [5, 4], 'col1_B': [10, 9], 'col2_A': [15, 14], 'col2_B': [20, 19]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# Get all the number index inside 'col' columns name
col_idx = [re.findall(r'\d+', name)[0] for name in list(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('col')])]
# Get all the alphabet suffix at end of 'col' columns name
col_sfx = [name.split('_')[-1] for name in list(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('col')])]

# Get unique value in list
col_idx = list(dict.fromkeys(col_idx))
col_sfx = list(dict.fromkeys(col_sfx))

# Create new df with repeated 'Name' and 'col'
new_d = {'Name': [name for name in df['Name'] for i in range(len(col_sfx))], 'col': col_sfx * len(df.index)}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_d)

all_sub_df = []
all_sub_df.append(new_df)
print("Name and col:\n{}\n".format(new_df))

# Create new df for each val columns
for i_c in col_idx:
  df_coli = df.filter(like='col' + i_c, axis=1)
  df_coli = df_coli.stack().reset_index()
  df_coli = df_coli[df_coli.columns[-1:]]
  df_coli.columns = ['val_' + i_c]
  print("df_col{}:\n{}\n".format(i_c, df_coli))
  all_sub_df.append(df_coli)

# Concatenate all columns for result
new_df = pd.concat(all_sub_df, axis=1)
new_df
```

Outputs:

```
Name and col:
  Name col
0   AA   A
1   AA   B
2   BB   A
3   BB   B

df_col1:
   val_1
0      5
1     10
2      4
3      9

df_col2:
   val_2
0     15
1     20
2     14
3     19

    Name    col     val_1   val_2
0   AA  A   5   15
1   AA  B   10  20
2   BB  A   4   14
3   BB  B   9   19
```